# jQuery slideDown/slideUp issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, slidedown

I can't get the jQuery slideDown effect to work. I'm trying to get a panel to show by sliding down. Instead it just shows like the show() method but in Firefox it doesn't even show.

jQuery:

```
$("#linkHBE").click(function(){
    if ($(".panel").is(":hidden")) {
        $(".panel").show("slow");
    } 
    else 
        $(".panel").hide("slow");
});
```

The HTML:

```
 <div class="panel"></div>

 <ul id="grid">
      <li class="web"><a id="linkHBE"><img  width="296px" height="196px"></a></li>
      <li class="graphic"><img width="296px" height="196px"></li>
      <li class="web"><img width="296px" height="196px"></li>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#linkHBE").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.panel').toggle(1000); // fadeToggle() or slideToggle() are also available
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DVS9x/3/)**

---

Here, `e.preventDefault()` is for prevent the page reload to click on anchor tag. jQuery **[`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle)** will do show-hide for you. So, no additional checking needed.

---

**Related refs:**

- **[preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault)**
- **[fadeToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle)**
- **[slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle)**

Comment: It doesn't make any difference. It works on jFiddle but not on my page.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code is not working is because your handler isn't cancelling the default event, so the browser is following the link. Try this:

```
$("#linkHBE").click(function(e){
    $(".panel").slideToggle("slow");
    e.preventDefault();
});
```